# Dell XPS 13 Sputnik3 (Ubuntu 14.04) cannot find display-port

Tags: xorg, dell, display, xrandr, xps

Here is the story. I've used the mini-display port from my XPS13 for about a year with an ASUS 2560x1440 res external display, via a mini-DP to DP connector. This has worked fine for 1 year.

This afternoon, I tried to connect my mini-display port to a projector via a mini-DP to HDMI, and nothing happened. I had heard that sometimes there were issues with projectors and XPS Ubuntu DisplayPort, so I unplugged and didn't worry about it.

When I came back to my desk and plugged in my usual external monitor, my XPS 13 was unable to find the monitor. Usually when that happens, I try and manually add a mode with xrandr, like:

```
xrandr --addmode DP1 2560x1440
xrandr --output DP1 --mode 2560x1440 --right-of LVDS1
```

When I went to do that, the DP1 output didn't even show as disconnected...this caused (and still is causing) me quite a fright.

Output from xrandr -q:

```
calvin@silversputnik:~$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     48.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Any help would be appreciated, do I need to reset xrandr? or reload a kernel?

Kind Regards

---

**Update**

I installed intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_amd64.deb fresh from Intel HD graphics.

Now I am seeing the DP1 when plugged in, and I see this in xrandr -q:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440      60.0*+
   1920x1080      60.0 +   60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1440x576       50.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   1440x480       60.0     59.9  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

MY eDP1 (native display is gone).

Comment: I am having a similar issue, where sometimes the external monitor works and sometimes it doesn't.  When it is working xrandr shows an display called 'HDMI1', and when it doesn't that display is missing from the output.  I am looking into this further.